# Android Studio JAVA_HOME is set right but not?

Tags: android-studio, java-home

I have a little problem with Android Studio and the `JAVA_HOME`. It is set right with the environment variables and is saying it's on a whole another drive

[image: JAVA_HOME PATH]

This is the Error Message

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: D:\IDES
```

Please set the `JAVA_HOME` variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.

(IDES is where I saved Android Studio and other IDEs)

Is there something I'm missing. It came out of nowhere was coding something in dart(flutter) and then tried to test it then this message came. Before that, I already started the app once to make sure everything works.

Comment: Hi, did you set the PATH in user variables or system variables?

Comment: if you mean the JDK path into PATH yes into system variables

Answer (score 0):

I somehow got it working i moved the JDK into a separate folder into the drive where Android studio is and changed the folder name where it's stored i dont really know what of those 2 things repaired it